# python asyncio, 405 ответ на post запрос к серверу

Tags: python, asyncio

Имеется приложение на python/asyncio

```
from src.infrastucture.http import http_server

http_server.run()
```

```
import json, asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from schema import Schema
from src.infrastucture.config.config import Config


def run():

    # Runs webserver.

    app = web.Application(middlewares=[auth])

    app.add_routes([web.post('/', handle)])

    host = Config().app['app_host']
    port = Config().app['app_port']

    web.run_app(app, host=host, port=port)
```

Приложение успешно работает и обрабатывает post-запросы на локалхосте. Но на сервере в яндексклауде приложение отказывается принимать post-запросы, отвечая 405 статусом. При это спокойно принимает get-запросы, хотя вроде бы явно указано `web.post('/', handle)`

Nginx не использую, просто запускаю приложение и все.

Кто-нибудь подскажет как объяснить такое поведение и сделать так чтобы приложение начало принимать пост-запросы?

Comment: что в переменной `host`?

Comment: app_host=0.0.0.0 app_port=9191